# Session count window function does not find database index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-performance, window-functions

I'm counting the user sessions, defined as events that happen within 30 minutes.
The sessions are in respect to a dynamic `course_id`.

This is the working query:

```
SELECT user_uuid, COUNT(*) as sessions_metric
  FROM (
    SELECT
      user_uuid,
      created_at - lag(created_at) over (PARTITION BY user_uuid
                                         ORDER BY created_at) as working_time
    FROM events
    WHERE in_context->>'course_id' = '{course_id}'
  ) as q
  WHERE extract(epoch from working_time) > 1800
  group by user_uuid
```

Here is the short query plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=29142.78..29218.68 rows=595 width=37) (actual time=9548.198..11560.178 rows=5457 loops=1)
  Group Key: q.user_uuid
  ->  Subquery Scan on q  (cost=29142.78..29209.76 rows=595 width=37) (actual time=9548.091..11544.903 rows=21523 loops=1)
        Filter: (date_part('epoch'::text, q.working_time) > '1800'::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 334633
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=29142.78..29182.97 rows=1786 width=45) (actual time=9548.051..11315.139 rows=356156 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=29142.78..29147.25 rows=1786 width=45) (actual time=9548.037..10757.296 rows=356156 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: events.user_uuid, events.created_at
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 20152kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..29046.31 rows=1786 width=45) (actual time=0.012..603.213 rows=356156 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((in_context ->> 'course_id'::text) = 'my-course-id'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1065
Planning time: 0.218 ms
Execution time: 11578.920 ms
```

Analyzing the attached verbose query plan using http://tatiyants.com/pev/ I see that the **sorting** by `by user_uuid, created_at desc` within the window function is what takes the longest time.

No matter which indexes I tried, I cannot get the planner to use the index to speed up the sorting.

What would be the correct index in this case?

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Aggregate",
      "Strategy": "Sorted",
      "Startup Cost": 29142.78,
      "Total Cost": 29218.68,
      "Plan Rows": 595,
      "Plan Width": 37,
      "Actual Startup Time": 12829.400,
      "Actual Total Time": 15011.769,
      "Actual Rows": 5457,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": ["q.user_uuid", "count(*)"],
      "Group Key": ["q.user_uuid"],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 15689,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 7999,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 2524,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 2524,
      "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
      "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Subquery Scan",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Alias": "q",
          "Startup Cost": 29142.78,
          "Total Cost": 29209.76,
          "Plan Rows": 595,
          "Plan Width": 37,
          "Actual Startup Time": 12829.281,
          "Actual Total Time": 14994.034,
          "Actual Rows": 21523,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": ["q.user_uuid", "q.working_time", "events.created_at"],
          "Filter": "(date_part('epoch'::text, q.working_time) > '1800'::double precision)",
          "Rows Removed by Filter": 334633,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 15689,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 7999,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 2524,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 2524,
          "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
          "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "WindowAgg",
              "Parent Relationship": "Subquery",
              "Startup Cost": 29142.78,
              "Total Cost": 29182.97,
              "Plan Rows": 1786,
              "Plan Width": 45,
              "Actual Startup Time": 12829.234,
              "Actual Total Time": 14740.186,
              "Actual Rows": 356156,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Output": ["events.user_uuid", "(events.created_at - lag(events.created_at) OVER (?))", "events.created_at"],
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 15689,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 7999,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 2524,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 2524,
              "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
              "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Sort",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Startup Cost": 29142.78,
                  "Total Cost": 29147.25,
                  "Plan Rows": 1786,
                  "Plan Width": 45,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 12829.218,
                  "Actual Total Time": 14132.416,
                  "Actual Rows": 356156,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": ["events.user_uuid", "events.created_at"],
                  "Sort Key": ["events.user_uuid", "events.created_at"],
                  "Sort Method": "external merge",
                  "Sort Space Used": 20152,
                  "Sort Space Type": "Disk",
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 15689,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 7999,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 2524,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 2524,
                  "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Relation Name": "events",
                      "Schema": "public",
                      "Alias": "events",
                      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                      "Total Cost": 29046.31,
                      "Plan Rows": 1786,
                      "Plan Width": 45,
                      "Actual Startup Time": 2.623,
                      "Actual Total Time": 2268.859,
                      "Actual Rows": 356156,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Output": ["events.user_uuid", "events.created_at"],
                      "Filter": "((events.in_context ->> 'course_id'::text) = 'my-course-id'::text)",
                      "Rows Removed by Filter": 1065,
                      "Shared Hit Blocks": 15689,
                      "Shared Read Blocks": 7999,
                      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                      "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                      "I/O Write Time": 0.000
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.207,
    "Triggers": [
    ],
    "Execution Time": 15030.554
  }
]
```

Comment: The output of `explain (analyze)` would have been more useful if you had posted the "plain text" format, not the json. But nevertheless there is a huge gap between the estimated rows for the events table (1786 rows vs. 356156). Looks like your statistics are way off. Does running `analyze events` change anything? But as you are reading nearly all rows from that table (the where condition only removed 1065 rows), an index is not going to help a lot.

Comment: Ok, I've done analyze events and then switched the plain text for the `explain (analyze)`. Of course, almost every row has to be scanned, but can't I speed up the sorting that is performed (as mentioned in the question)?

Comment: Did you try an index on `(user_uuid, created_at desc)` or on `(user_uuid, created_at desc, in_context->>'course_id')`. Your sort also spills to disk: `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 20152kB` try to  increase `work_mem` until this can be done in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `work_mem`. Yes, I tried both, but they are simply not used.

Comment: I thought I needed a partial index, but no idea how to specify a dynamic course id then

Comment: `create index on events (user_uuid, created_at desc, in_context->>'course_id')` or if the course_id does reduce the number of rows substantially put it first: `create index on events ( in_context->>'course_id', user_uuid, created_at desc)`. But as I said: if you are going to read (nearly) all rows, it's unlikely Postgres will use an index at all